# Editing a Dataview from a joined list

Tags: 2007, database

I think I want to do something simple, but it seems maybe I am not doing it the way you are supposed to.

I need to use Sharepoint Designer 2007 to create a website, code behind is highly likely to be not allowed on this site. So, it sounded like a simple request, show a web front end to a database that emplotees can see, update and save. This can then be analysed from a higher level to get information regarding all employees by running queries on said database.

Thus far, I have a series of tables in a database that are linked. So I have a table that stores competencies for all employees. So amongst other tables I have a I have a table of competencies:

```
CompetencyId | Code | Description
```

Then in the CompetencyScores table:

```
CompetencyScoreId | EmployeeId_FK | CompetencyId_FK | CompetencyRating_FK
```

Each employee will have the same competencies so it is easy enough to create a read-only view of these joined tables but I don't want read-only, I want to be able to edit the values. So, for example I want to be able to add a drop down list to be able to change the scores. If I create a linked data source then I cannot create an editable form. If I start with an editable form by using CompetencyScores as a table by itself whilst I can add the score as a drop down list by adding as a data source, I cannot add in Description as text as it only appears to allow drop down lists.

Comment: is it SQL database? how is this related to SharePoint?

Comment: @AndreyMarkeev Yes SQL. This is being displayed in a Sharepoint ASPX web page using the DataView and related controls. Maybe I wasn't obvious in that respect in the question

Comment: Aha, so you're working with SharePoint Designer? It would be great to add this information into your question.

Comment: @AndreyMarkeev Thanks for the pointer. I will update now.

Comment: How are you pulling this data into Sharepoint? Did you create ECTs and then use Business Data Lists to display the data?

Comment: @Perplexed I don't understand what that means. I am populating the data by creating databases in Visual Studio and then manually adding the data for now. I was led to believe that it should be straight-forward to use Sharepoint Designer to drag-and-drop a set of views for this data. I am beginning to think it is definitely not so straight-forward